# Before claiming prophethood,X was famous for being truthful among his people,so that is one of the proof that he is a prophet?

Tags: theology, philosophy-of-religion, islamic-philosophy, existence-of-god

some people who believe in the prophethood and divine inspiration of specific individuals ,use this argument,as one of the arguments,that proves that their believe in such individuals is legitimate

example: some mulsims claim that the prophet of Islam , was famous for being honest and truthful , before he began claiming divine inspiration, that even those who rejected his claims of prophethood ,confessed that he was famous for being honest and truthful , before he began claiming divine inspiration.... so this can be is one of the proof that he is a prophet...

other believers in other religions, argue the same..

is this arguemnt valid?

Comment: This is invalid on its own. One does not have to be dishonest to be mistaken or delusional. However, it does make one alternative explanation unlikely, and so can be used in conjunction with other evidence.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that a prior reputation for being honest provides some weak evidence towards the truth of whatever a person says.

However, it's not very much evidence, because:

- A reputable person may still lie or be mistaken.
- Extraordinary claims, such as the claim a person is a prophet, require extraordinary proof. Plenty of people have a reputation for honesty; such a reputation is not extraordinary proof.
- We do not have an unbiased account of whether a famous prophet was actually honest. Those who revere him would tend to describe him in a positive light, whether he had been honest or not, so we cannot trust them to give an unbiased account.

So, given that a claimed prophet is *reported* to have been honest prior to prophethood, the probability that he actually was honest does increase a little, and the probability that he actually was a prophet also increases a little. But it's not strong evidence.

Answer (score 1):

The idea that people can by and large be categorized as honest or dishonest is of a piece with the theory of character, the theory that people have the kind of statuses that support such overarching descriptions. [Much psychological evidence testifies against the belief in character traits, including (or especially) morally charged such traits](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-psych-emp/#VirtEthiSkepAbouChar):

> ... “character skeptics” contend that if moral conduct varies so sharply, often for the worse, with minor perturbations in circumstance, ostensibly good character provides very limited assurance of good conduct. In addition to this claim in descriptive psychology, concerning the fragility of moral character, some character skeptics also forward a thesis in normative ethics, to the effect that character merits less attention in ethical thought than it traditionally gets.

So if a supposed prophet has a reputation for honesty up until some time, this is consistent with his tendency towards honesty failing him when he turns to religious proclamations (if a supposed prophet had a habit of sexual activity involving children, or of executing hundreds of people, one wonders about his moral credibility even more). Less harshly, we might mention that [the onset of schizophrenia is usually in late adolescence or early adulthood](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3080674/), which shows that people can be more mentally balanced up until a certain time, less so afterwards. (Note that sometimes schizophrenia might not develop, or at least not be detected, until even later in life, but is then still an example of how someone's personality can be altered significantly over time, to the detriment of appeals to their past character.)

---

Generally speaking, if a divine being would like to send messages to the entire world, it would behoove such a being to send those messages to the entire world, not to a few select men (almost always men, and often violent ones at that) who must then be specifically trusted, in addition to whatever trust one thinks to place in a divine being. People who claim to be special prophets are *prime facie* untrustworthy for reason of that very claim, in other words.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not serve as any form of evidence, if evidence is meant to mean facts that make the truth **evident**.

A person having a reputation for being reliable or honest does **not** imply that he is a prophet if he claims to have seen an angel. No matter what the testimony is, one must prove that it is even possible for angels or a god to exist. Given this logical gap, you cannot claim, even **probabilistically**, that his reputation is relevant as evidence

Answer (score -2):

some guy said this "A reputable person may still lie or be mistaken.
Extraordinary claims, such as the claim a person is a prophet, require extraordinary proof. Plenty of people have a reputation for honesty; such a reputation is not extraordinary proof.
We do not have an unbiased account of whether a famous prophet was actually honest. Those who revere him would tend to describe him in a positive light, whether he had been honest or not, so we cannot trust them to give an unbiased account." extraordinary claims requiring extraordinary evidence just means they require STRONG evidence, and trustworthiness is strong evidence, so in fact if you can prove that Muhammad likely wasn't crazy and still trustworthy then you could say that he at least saw something real, and why are you wondering whether he had to lie in THIS case? Just because people lie about these thing and hallucinate these things doesn't mean that all of these things have to be from craziness or lies, how many people have lied about being rich, rich people still exist right? How many have claimed to be geniuses, many right. And many crazy people who aren't genius think they are, but geniuses still exist right? And he wasn't mistaken if he gave a vivid description of an angel that told him he was a prophet. So really the first and second points are weak in my stance. I'm not muslim but I'll become muslim. I decided to be muslim since therei s evidence for Islam

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146921/discussion-on-answer-by-loopit-before-claiming-prophethood-x-was-famous-for-bein); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.